# Getting token from a windows form app get stuck when trying to get a secret form Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-authentication

I am trying to read key vault keys from a windows form app. When I call following:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://xxtestingkeyvault.vault.azure.net/"), new InteractiveBrowserCredential());
var test =  client.GetSecret("Test");
```

It just get stuck. I would expect a browser to popup. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

OK found a solution. If i took a .Core Console Application it worked. I then tried using the .NET Windows Forms (and not the .NET Framework version) and added the code to an event from a button. Still same. I then added the code in the Form_Load event. Then it worked. So there is something in the event model that requires it to be in the start-up of the application. If I add it in the Form_Load of the .NET Framework version it does still not work.